# How to use fprintf with complex values

Tags: matlab, printing

My code computes the real and imaginary parts of `V1` as follows:

```
V1=term1/term3 + term2/term3 * i
fprintf( 'Slope V1 = %.4f\n', real(V1), imag(V1) )
```

I want to output the complex number `V1` as follows:

```
Slope of V1 = real(V1) + imag(V1) * i
```

I  never seem to get the `%4.f` notation correct. Can someone give me a start with this, please? I am not sure how to handle the + sign.

```
V1=term1/term3 + term2/term3 *i
fprintf( 'Slope V1 = %.4f\n', real(V1), imag(V1) )
```

Outputs

```
Slope V1 = 0.0000
Slope V1 = 1.4142
```

I want to have output

```
Slope V1 = 0.0000+1.4142i
```

Sincerely,
MM

Comment: These were all great suggestions and gave a thorough look at complex number printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using two format specifiers for the two values you want to print?

```
fprintf( 'Slope V1 = %.4f + %.4f i\n', real(V1), imag(V1) )
```

Or, even better ([as Hunter Jiang suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174355/how-to-use-fprintf-with-complex-values/54174635?noredirect=1#comment95182736_54174635)):

```
fprintf( 'Slope V1 = %.4f%+.4fi\n', real(V1), imag(V1) )
```

...by including the `+` in the format specifier, the second number will always be preceded by either a "-" or a "+" depending on the sign of the value. For negative imaginary numbers this prevents printing "+ -".

Comment: I got the following to work: fprintf('Slope of L1 = %.4f + %.4fi\n', real(V1), imag(V1))
The plus sign works just fine this way. I had put in in quotes! Your comments were helpful.

Comment: As far as I concerned, `fprintf( 'Slope V1 = %.4f %+.4f i\n', real(V1), imag(V1) )` might be better, as it will show only one sign marks for those complex numbers with negative imaginary part.

Comment: @Hunter: Fantastic! I had not thought of that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a value you have two options:

**1.** `disp(z);`

**2.** `fprintf("Slope V1 = %.4f %+.fi\n', real(V1), imag(V1)")`

*note that disp ends with a new line while fprintf doesn't that's why we use ' \n '*

As for the `%4.f` you use it if you want the number to be indented by 4 whitespaces and take just the integer part.
if you want to set the precision to 4 digits after the decimal point you would use `%.4f`

Let's say we want to display 12.1234

```
%4.f:   12
%.4f:12.1234
%.2f:12.12
%10.2f:        12.12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), which automatically handles complex numbers:

```
fprintf(['Slope V1 = ' num2str(1+1j, '%.4f')])
```

or

```
fprintf('Slope V1 = %s', num2str(1+1j, '%.4f'))
```